# How to Efficiently Render Car Movement Tracks from Geospatial Data?

Tags: algorithm, performance, visualization, geospatial, data-processing

I'm facing an issue with building car movement tracks using geospatial data in my database. I have a large amount of data (lat, lon, timestamp, etc.) capturing the movement of cars, and I need to generate historical tracks on a map for specific time intervals. Initially, when I transmitted all the data, it resulted in a 17-megabyte JSON file for just six months of data for a single car. To optimize this, I applied a track simplification algorithm that reduced the number of points, sacrificing some level of detail. As a result, the data size was reduced to 3 megabytes for the same time period. However, this still seems like a substantial amount of data, and the calculations are quite time-consuming, taking around 6 seconds.

I've observed that platforms like Google Maps and other websites can display tracks with good quality by transmitting no more than 500 kilobytes of data, even for longer distances. I'm curious to know how others typically solve such a problem. Are there any best practices or techniques to efficiently handle and render car movement tracks? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to optimize the data size and calculation time while maintaining reasonable track quality. Thank you in advance!

My code:

```golang
package services

import (
    "go_geo_api/models"
    "go_geo_api/repositories"
    "log"
    "math"
    "sync"
)

const deg2rad = math.Pi / 180

type TracksService struct {
    Repo *repositories.DeviceRepository
    Eps  float64
    Log  *log.Logger
}

func NewTracksService(deviceRepository *repositories.DeviceRepository, eps float64, logger *log.Logger) *TracksService {
    return &TracksService{
        Repo: deviceRepository,
        Eps:  eps,
        Log:  logger,
    }
}

func (s *TracksService) GetTracks(trackListRequest models.TrackListRequest) (map[string][]models.TrackResponse, error) {
    pointsByDevices, err := s.Repo.GetDevicePointsByTime(
        trackListRequest.Devices,
        trackListRequest.TimestampStart,
        trackListRequest.TimestampEnd,
    )

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    answer := make(map[string][]models.TrackResponse, len(pointsByDevices))
    for deviceID, points := range pointsByDevices {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(deviceID string, points []models.DevicePointWithoutID) {
            defer wg.Done()
            deviceTracks, err := s.calculateTracks(points, trackListRequest.StopWindow)
            if err != nil {
                s.Log.Printf("Error calculating tracks for device %s: %s\n", deviceID, err)
                return
            }
            answer[deviceID] = deviceTracks
        }(deviceID, points)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    return answer, nil
}

func (s *TracksService) calculateTracks(points []models.DevicePointWithoutID, stopWindow int) ([]models.TrackResponse, error) {
    if len(points) == 0 {
        return []models.TrackResponse{}, nil
    }

    // Initialize track and point data
    currentTrackDistance := 0.0
    currentTrackTime := 0.0
    tracks := make([]models.TrackResponse, 0, len(points))
    currentTrackPoints := make([]models.DevicePointWithoutID, 0, len(points))
    currentTrackPoints = append(currentTrackPoints, points[0])

    lastPoint := points[0]

    for i := 1; i < len(points); i++ {
        currentPoint := points[i]

        distanceBetweenPoints := s.geoDistance(lastPoint.Lat, lastPoint.Lon, currentPoint.Lat, currentPoint.Lon)
        timedeltaBetweenPoints := currentPoint.Timestamp.Sub(lastPoint.Timestamp).Seconds()

        isStoppedForALongTime := timedeltaBetweenPoints > float64(stopWindow)
        hasDrivenDistance := distanceBetweenPoints >= 10

        // Checking if the device has stopped for a long time or traveled a distance
        if isStoppedForALongTime || hasDrivenDistance {
            tracks = s.finishCurrentTrackAndStartNewOne(tracks, currentTrackPoints, currentTrackDistance, currentTrackTime, currentPoint)
            currentTrackPoints = []models.DevicePointWithoutID{currentPoint}
            currentTrackDistance = 0.0
            currentTrackTime = 0.0
        } else {
            currentTrackDistance += distanceBetweenPoints
            currentTrackTime += timedeltaBetweenPoints
            currentTrackPoints = append(currentTrackPoints, currentPoint)
        }

        // If this is the last point and there is an unfinished track, complete it and add it to the tracks
        if i == len(points)-1 && len(currentTrackPoints) > 1 {
            tracks = s.finishCurrentTrackAndStartNewOne(tracks, currentTrackPoints, currentTrackDistance, currentTrackTime, currentPoint)
        }

        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }

    return tracks, nil
}

func (s *TracksService) finishCurrentTrackAndStartNewOne(tracks []models.TrackResponse, currentTrackPoints []models.DevicePointWithoutID, currentTrackDistance float64, currentTrackTime float64, currentPoint models.DevicePointWithoutID) []models.TrackResponse {
    if len(currentTrackPoints) > 1 {
        avgSpeed := s.calculateAvgSpeed(currentTrackDistance, currentTrackTime)
        simplifiedTrackPoints := s.simplifyTrackPoints(currentTrackPoints, s.Eps)
        tracks = append(tracks, s.createNewTrack(currentTrackDistance, avgSpeed, simplifiedTrackPoints))
    }
    return tracks
}

func (s *TracksService) createNewTrack(currentTrackDistance float64, avgSpeed float64, simplifiedTrackPoints []models.DevicePointWithoutID) models.TrackResponse {
    return models.TrackResponse{
        Distance: round(currentTrackDistance, 2),
        AvgSpeed: round(avgSpeed, 2),
        Points:   simplifiedTrackPoints,
    }
}

func (s *TracksService) calculateAvgSpeed(currentTrackDistance float64, currentTrackTime float64) float64 {
    if currentTrackTime == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return currentTrackDistance / currentTrackTime * 3600 // Speed ​​conversion in km/h
}

func (s *TracksService) geoDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 float64) float64 {
    // Convert degrees to radians
    dLat := (lat2 - lat1) * deg2rad
    dLon := (lon2 - lon1) * deg2rad

    // Apply the Haversine formula
    lat1 *= deg2rad
    lat2 *= deg2rad

    a := math.Pow(math.Sin(dLat/2), 2) + math.Pow(math.Sin(dLon/2), 2)*math.Cos(lat1)*math.Cos(lat2)
    c := 2 * math.Asin(math.Sqrt(a))

    return 6371.0 * c
}

// simplifyTrackPoints simplifies track points using the Douglas-Pecker algorithm.
func (s *TracksService) simplifyTrackPoints(points []models.DevicePointWithoutID, epsilon float64) []models.DevicePointWithoutID {
    if len(points) < 3 {
        return points
    }

    // Finding the point with the maximum distance
    dmax := float64(0)
    index := 0
    end := len(points) - 1

    for i := 1; i < end; i++ {
        d := s.perpendicularDistance(points[i], points[0], points[end])
        if d > dmax {
            index = i
            dmax = d
        }
    }

    // If the maximum distance is greater than epsilon, recursively simplify
    var result []models.DevicePointWithoutID

    if dmax > epsilon {
        // Recursive call
        recResults1 := s.simplifyTrackPoints(points[:index+1], epsilon)
        recResults2 := s.simplifyTrackPoints(points[index:], epsilon)

        // Creating a list of results
        result = append(result, recResults1[:len(recResults1)-1]...)
        result = append(result, recResults2...)
    } else {
        result = []models.DevicePointWithoutID{points[0], points[end]}
    }

    return result
}

// perpendicularDistance calculates the perpendicular distance from a point to a line formed by two points.
func (s *TracksService) perpendicularDistance(point models.DevicePointWithoutID, linePoint1 models.DevicePointWithoutID, linePoint2 models.DevicePointWithoutID) float64 {
    // Area of ​​a triangle
    area := math.Abs(0.5 * ((linePoint1.Lat-linePoint2.Lat)*point.Lon + (linePoint2.Lon-linePoint1.Lon)*point.Lat + (linePoint1.Lon*linePoint2.Lat - linePoint2.Lon*linePoint1.Lat)))
    // Triangle base (distance between line points)
    base := s.geoDistance(linePoint1.Lat, linePoint1.Lon, linePoint2.Lat, linePoint2.Lon)

    // The distance is twice the area divided by the base
    distance := 2 * area / base

    return distance
}

func round(num float64, precision int) float64 {
    output := math.Pow(10, float64(precision))
    return math.Round(num*output) / output
}
```

Response example:

```json
{
    "devices": [
        {
            "device_id": "0622885e-0203-4859-9723-c96023224645",
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "distance": 2.03,
                    "avg_speed": 26.53,
                    "points": [
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:55:12+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.682621002197266,
                            "lon": 43.51759338378906,
                            "speed": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:55:18+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.68246841430664,
                            "lon": 43.5175895690918,
                            "speed": 13
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:55:25+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.68235778808594,
                            "lon": 43.5173454284668,
                            "speed": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:55:53+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.68218994140625,
                            "lon": 43.51645278930664,
                            "speed": 9
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:56:08+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.68138885498047,
                            "lon": 43.5166130065918,
                            "speed": 24
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:56:21+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.68075180053711,
                            "lon": 43.51652145385742,
                            "speed": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:57:11+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.68046188354492,
                            "lon": 43.513771057128906,
                            "speed": 18
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:57:21+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.68077850341797,
                            "lon": 43.513492584228516,
                            "speed": 19
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:58:32+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.683135986328125,
                            "lon": 43.51316833496094,
                            "speed": 15
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:58:36+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.68328094482422,
                            "lon": 43.512996673583984,
                            "speed": 18
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:58:58+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.682830810546875,
                            "lon": 43.50981140136719,
                            "speed": 56
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": "2023-06-09T09:59:47+06:00",
                            "lat": 43.68220138549805,
                            "lon": 43.4982795715332,
                            "speed": 69
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: 1. We need to see some of your data to make optimization suggestions. 2. JSON is far from a space efficient way to stare data. A binary format that is also compressed needs far less memory.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, a binary protocol will save some memory.  Second you can save more if you immediately compress with something lightweight like [Snappy](https://github.com/google/snappy).

But you can also use a Swinging Door trending algorithm to drop most points immediately, before encoding, with little degradation of the signal.  This algorithm can be found many places online, https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/using-the-swinging-door-trending-algorithm-in-postgresql_595129 is an example with a good explanation.

For your particular application, if you can turn the geospatial into a road + distance marker, then you can turn long parts of the drive - even through windy territory, into just a few data points.